# if condition with list comprehension in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, list-comprehension

i have a list contains some values.I want to check if any of the element is presented in another list with if statement.
I have done something like if condition with list comprehension this but not working as expected.
my code is

```
fileop=["create","open","append","delete","move","copy"]   
a=raw_input("enter a command\n")    
tokens=a.split(" ")

def data(i):    
     return i

if [data(i) in tokens for i in fileop] in tokens:    
     print "file operations"

     if "create" in tokens:    
        print "create"    
     elif "open" in tokens:    
        print "open"
     elif "delete" in tokens:    
         print "delete"
```

If my input is like delete file.how to get the correct keyword.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: not sure what you want but I am guessing [x for x in tokens if x in fileop]

Comment: @StephenRauch- it is for checking a list with another.That is any of the element in fileop is presented in tokens (list).i can do it like 'if "create" in tokens or "open in tokens" or  "delete in tokens": '.But i am just trying to implement it using list comprehension.

Comment: Please provide a sample input and output. Your code may look like Python, but it's using constructs that only mean something to you. We could help you convert those constructs to proper Python, but only if we know what they are meant to do.

Comment: My guess is you want `any` at some point if you want an if statement

Comment: don't post code with input or raw_input when you can just say sample_input = "delete file". Then you can say what the expected output is, because you know for sure what the input was.  Do you specifically want a list comprehension, or are the given answers sufficient?

Comment: If you are checking if the given input of command has the one of the operation given in a list `fileop`, use set and take intersection (`res = tokens.intersection(fileop)` or `res = tokens & fileop`) and then you can compare the result for matching operation. It will return empty set if None matched.

Comment: I got what i needed from  Kevins and Ryan.It's working.Thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re close to two different solutions here! One is to make a list (well, an iterable) of true or false values indicating whether each item of `fileop` is in `tokens`, then check if [*any*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) one is true:

```
if any(data(i) in tokens for i in fileop):
```

The other is to check if the set intersection between the tokens and the operations isn’t empty:

```
if set(tokens) & set(fileop):
```

The former is more typical, but this might have been what you were going for with the second `in tokens`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the tokens corresponding to file operations in the input, we can do:

```
operations = [token for token in tokens if token in fileop]
```

operations will be a list containing all tokens that represented a file operation

For example:

```
tokens = ["open", "move", "rename"]
```

operations will contain ["open", "move"]

If you want to print the list:

```
for fileop in [token for token in tokens if token in fileop]: 
    print fileop
```